# How to create redirect url for tracking?

Tags: php, redirect

I saw multiple websites have this functionality but Google can't find a clear way to do this.

In many sites, all their external / internal links first start with their domain name followed with parameters or a hash string, for example -- `http://sitename.com/?hashurl1`. When user clicks that link, user will be redirected to the other site. With this mechanism, they can track user activities, like Slickdeals.

Is there an library or tool we can use to archive this functionality?

I was thinking about using a database to store all the links and write a program to do the redirect and logging. However, I don't want to start from scratch if there is already an open-source project I can use directly.

I found some commercial service and plugin that has this functionality, but I want to understand the underlying detail of it.

Add: 
What I need are two things. 
1. When a user post an arbitrary URL, system will shorten it, just like what Twitter do when a user tweet a url.
2. Track anyone click that URL.

Now I think about combining goo.gl with Google analytics, use AJAX or do it in server site to shorten url when user post a content. But Goo.gl only provide statistic for a single url. How to connect it with  Google analytics to get whole site activities?

Comment: what you are looking for is `$_GET` + `header()`, plus whatever database you want, of course

Comment: Isn't this basically what google analytics does? (http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: If you just want to redirect and log, there is no need for a secondary project; all of your links could be in the format `redirect.php?link=$link` (where `$link` is either an URL-encoded format of the actual URL or a hash of it (maybe base64, or custom)). Then, redirect.php just logs it to a database. If you want analytics beyond that, try Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Google Analytics?  You can then easily tag the URL's to track certain points (called events, campaigns, etc.).

To see the type of url formatting.  Try this tool

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

NOTE:  That if you want to track internal functions.  Don't use campaigns, use event tracking.  If you were to use campaign tracking.  It would overwrite things like a Google Adwords Campaign tracking etc.  Good way to remember Campaigns are normally used for getting customers to your website, and events are for tracking what the user does on the site.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use $_GET (or path info) to grab the values passed to your redirect PHP script, store what you need in the tracking database and extract the url from the passed hash.

Finally redirect the end user to the requested URL by sending the Location header:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Important: You cannot send any other data to console before the header, this will break your code. This means no echo "something" before the header is sent.